# Connect ddwrt with Server via VPN

Tags: router, vpn, routing, dd-wrt

I have a Server in the Internet and an dd-wrt Router behind some Firewalls. 
I would like to have Access to the dd-wrt via the Server. 
The only way to accomplish this is to have a VPN connection from the Router to the server.
The purpose is only that I can connect from the Server to the router. All normal Traffic from the Router should be Routed wihtout VPN.

Is there a good solution for my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

dd-wrt has its own vpn server, so it is possible to connect to that vpn server from any client.  you must activate this server in dd-wrt first of course

```
services>vpn>pptp server activate (in web interface)
```

you setup user, password and other information you need... then on the server, you simply install a pptp client and connect it to DD-WRT.

you did not mention what type of server you have...